# Programmatically measure DHTML total transfer size

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control, gzip

I have a few simultaneous profiling requirements that seem to exclude each others' ideal toolsets. I am working in C#, measuring the network transfer size & load time for the complete set of "polite load" content of a script, frame, and all ensuing constituent parts. I'm kicking this off as a step in a deployment process and logging the results programmatically, so Firebug or the other F12 options... aren't. The measurements must:

- Measure the effects of gzip/deflate compression
- Load elements initiated by javascript/DHTML, as well as images referenced by stylesheets
- Calculate the delta when browser caching is on/off (*some* elements will be sent with the cache-control *private* header)

The stock .NET 3.5 WebBrowser Control gives me javascript and DHTML handling for timing purposes, but no measurement of transfer size as best I can tell. I suppose I could traverse the DOM and separately issue HttpWebRequests for any element with a *src* attribute, but I'd like to avoid that of course. TIA for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler has an API: http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/dev/.  It allows automation (ExecAction.exe).  Don't know if it supports all the metrics you're looking for.